# PHP - run code only on successful switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

Looking for an easier way to accomplish:

```
$switch_success = false;
switch ($var){
    case "a":
        // do some stuff
        $switch_success = true;
        break;
    case "b":
        // do some stuff
        $switch_success = true;
        break;
    case "c":
        // do some stuff
        $switch_success = true;
        break;
}
if ($switch_success){
    // switch was successful - run once only if switch finds a matching case
}
```

Maybe another case keyword like `default` only for `any` or `all`:

```
case "c":
    // do some stuff
    break;
all:
    // switch was successful - run once only if switch finds a matching case
```

Or maybe ...

```
$switch_success = switch ($var){
    case "a":
    // do some stuff
    break;
    case "b":
    // do some stuff
    break;
    case "c":
    // do some stuff
    break;
}
if ($switch_success) //...
```

Just tried that to no avail, but just trying to illustrate my intent.

Comment: what would an unsuccessful switch look like? A runtime exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$switch_success=1;` at the top, and `default: $switch_success=0;` at the end of the switch.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like...

```
$switch_success = true;
switch ($var)
{
    case "a":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case "b":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case "c":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    default:
        $switch_success = false;
}
if ($switch_success){
    // switch was successful - run once only if switch finds a matching case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` clause has fall-through by default.

```
switch ($var){
    case "a":
    case "b":
    case "c":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    default
        // do nothing
        break;
}
```

But if you have stuff to do for each case, and then stuff to do for all of then, your original example is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want $success to be true if *any* of the cases are met, and false otherwise?  If so, set $success = true; at the start, and have your "default" case be $success = false;  Then you don't have to type $success = true; a bunch of times.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
$switch_success = true;
switch ($var){
    case "a":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case "b":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case "c":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    default:
        $switch_success = false;
        break;
}
if ($switch_success){
    // switch was successful - run once only if switch finds a matching case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a shorter version

```
if ($var == 'a' || $var == 'b' || $var == 'c') // do some stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd set `$switch_success` separately, like:

```
$switch_success = in_array($var, array("a","b","c"));

switch ($var) {
    case "a":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case "b":
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case "c":
        // do some stuff
        break;
}

if ($switch_success) {
    // switch was successful
}
```